# SEO Infinite scroll recommendation: does query string parameter matter for seo ranking of the infinite scroll page?

Tags: seo, google, pagination, infinite-scroll

The google "Infinite scroll search-friendly guideline" recommends to place `<link rel="next" href="fun-items?page=3"> <link rel="prev" href="fun-items?page=1">`tags in the head section of html.

They have suggested simple pagination where simple parameters like page=1, page=2 would do. We have complicated scenario where we have url like:

```
fun-items?lastrank=0&count=5;  //to fetch page1 data
fun-items?lastrank=5&count=10;   //to fetch page2 data
fun-items?lastrank=10&count=20;  //to fetch page3 data
```

The count=5,10,20 for page1,2,3 is also random so may vary time to time.

What would be the best thing to do SEO wise for such infinite scroll pages:

1. Give next and prev url as it is in next and prev rel tags: These may not be very clean next and prev url. but does that matter to google seo?
2. To keep clean URLs: Use page number i.e. page in url instead of these lengthy variables like "lastrank,count" and use these only for internal calculation.

And is it necessary to change the url when user enters the next page in infinite scroll? can such things have seo impact?

Comment: Pagination is rarely a good strategy for SEO at all.   Google doesn't usually index and rank pages very well except the first one.   Pagination does a poor job of getting links on subsequent pages crawled with PageRank.     As long as Google can see some initial content on your page with infinite scroll, I'd say it is no worse than pages with different URLs.

Comment: but what should we do for search page with 1 lakh products?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller any suggestions?